# Call multiple backing bean methods at the same time

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is there a way to call multiple methods from different backing beans in JSF?

I have an application that stores user information. I have multiple backing beans which are broken down into schedule, address, phone.. etc.

When the application initially loads everything works find but since all of my views are of type `@ViewScope` the lists of schedule, address, phone are maintained even if a new user is displayed.

I need to manually set the schedule, address, and phone lists to null when the user navigates away from the current person they are viewing IE I need to call a method in each managed bean at one point in time (When the user clicks on a commandLink).

Is it possible to call multiple bean methods on one commandLink?

Answer (score 31):

```
<h:commandLink action="#{jsfBean.submit}" value="execute multiple methods">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{jsfBean1.actionListener}"/>
    <f:actionListener binding="#{jsfBean2.actionListener}"/>
    <f:actionListener binding="#{jsfBean3.actionListener}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Using the above code, with methods in the beans have the ('default') signature of `actionListener(ActionEvent event)`

when you click the commandLink first the submit method will be executed. After that all the other actionListeners will be executed one by one...Hope that helps ;)

Comment: *"Note that the JSF implementation always invokes action listeners before actions."* - [Core JavaServer Faces (3rd ed.)](http://www.corejsf.com/), page 314.

Answer (score 2):

You can have your commandLink reference one method which itself calls all the necessary methods.

Answer (score 1):

The answers here were close to working for me but also had to add parenthesis to the methods in the f:actionListener:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{jsfBean.submit}" value="execute multiple methods">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{jsfBean1.actionListener()}"/>
    <f:actionListener binding="#{jsfBean2.actionListener()}"/>
    <f:actionListener binding="#{jsfBean3.actionListener()}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: That is only needed  (afaik) if your server side methods have that ('non-default') signature instead of `actionListener(ActionEvent event)`...

Comment: ahhhh ok. Thanks for the tip @Kukeltje