# Multiple action listeners with a single command component in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is it possible to invoke more than one listener method using a single command component? For example,

A view scoped bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class ViewScopedBean implements Serializable
{
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{sessionScopedBean}")
    private SessionScopedBean sessionScopedBean; //Getter/Setter.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ViewScopedBean() {}

    public void action()
    {
        //Do something.
        sessionScopedBean.action();
    }
}
```

A session scoped bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public final class SessionScopedBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SessionScopedBean () {}

    public void action() {
        //Do something.
    }
}
```

A command button like the one given below,

```
<h:commandButton value="Action" actionListener="#{viewScopedBean.action}"/>
```

invokes the method `action()` in `ViewScopedBean` which in turn invokes the `action()` method in `SessionScopedBean` by injecting an instance of that bean.

Is it somehow possible do the same on XHTML so that a need to inject a bean just to invoke a method can be eliminated?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`<f:actionListener binding>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/actionListener.html):

```
<h:commandButton value="Action">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{viewScopedBean.action()}"/>
    <f:actionListener binding="#{sessionScopedBean.action()}"/>
</h:commandButton />
```

Note the importance of the parentheses in EL. Omitting them would in this particular example otherwise throw a confusing `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'action' not found on type com.example.ViewScopedBean`, because it's by default interpreted as a value expression. Adding parentheses makes it a method expression. See also [Why am I able to bind <f:actionListener> to an arbitrary method if it's not supported by JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744949/why-am-i-able-to-bind-factionlistener-to-an-arbitrary-method-if-its-not-supp)

You could even add an `actionListener` and/or an `action` method to the component the usual way, which is invoked later on. What it has to be unique is the `action` method, which decides the **outcome** for the processing.

Anyway, keep in mind the listeners are always executed before the action and considered a "warming-up" for it. Your best is to perform the whole logic in the action method, even if you need to do bean injections.

**See also:**

- [Call multiple backing bean methods at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020492/call-multiple-backing-bean-methods-at-the-same-time)
- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/)